im new in django work with course but and still in same points for days why i have these a circular import?
.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'challenges.urls' from 'D:\djangoproject\mypage\challenges\urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see the 'urlpatterns' variable with valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
in urls.py
*
`from django.contrib import admin 
from django.urls import path , include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("challenges/", include("challenges.urls"))`,
]

in challenges/views
`from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse , HttpResponseNotFound

# Create your views here.
def monthly_challenge(request , month):
    challenge_text= None
    if month=="jan":
       challenge_text="jan"
    elif month=="feb":
        challenge_text="feb" 
    elif month=="march":
         challenge_text="march"
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotFound("not found")
    return HttpResponse(challenge_text)`

in challenges/urls
`from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.urls.resolvers import URLPattern

urlpattrens= [
    path("<month>" , views.monthly_challenge),
]`

